# Why do I lose the console output?

Tags: java, eclipse, stream

I have this code in a JUnit Test :

```
public class CvsCommandTest {
...
    @Test
    public void test() {
        PServerConnection con = new PServerConnection(root);
        GlobalOptions globalOptions = new GlobalOptions();
        globalOptions.setCVSRoot(root.toString());

        Client client = new Client(con, new StandardAdminHandler());
        client.setLocalPath(LOCAL_PATH);
        client.getEventManager().addCVSListener(new BasicListener());
        CheckoutCommand checkoutCmd = new CheckoutCommand();
        checkoutCmd.setBuilder(null);
        checkoutCmd.setModule("Outils");

        try {
            client.getConnection().open();
            LOG.info("CVS checkout : " + checkoutCmd.getCVSCommand());
            boolean successCheckout = client.executeCommand(checkoutCmd,globalOptions );
            LOG.info("Checkout COMPLETED : " + successCheckout);
...
```

The output, while debugging, is :

> [INFO] fr.package.CvsCommandTest - CVS checkout : checkout
>   -N Outils
>
> cvs checkout: Updating Outils

The first line is my log, the second comes from the listener but I don't get the remaining of my logs.
The basicListener is defined this way :

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.event.CVSAdapter;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.event.MessageEvent;

public class BasicListener extends CVSAdapter {

    /** * Stores a tagged line */
    private final StringBuffer taggedLine = new StringBuffer();

    /**
     * Called when the server wants to send a message to be displayed to the
     * user. The message is only for information purposes and clients can choose
     * to ignore these messages if they wish.
     * 
     * @param e
     *            the event
     */
    public void messageSent(MessageEvent e) {
        String line = e.getMessage();
        PrintStream stream = e.isError() ? System.err : System.out;
        if (e.isTagged()) {
            String message = MessageEvent.parseTaggedMessage(taggedLine, line);

            if (message != null) {
                stream.println(message);
            }
        } else {
            stream.println(line);
        }
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: System.out stream.close(); --> good night...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned comment in to answer

**System.out stream.close(); --> good night...**

Explanation:

Since he is using the `System.out` to output he's log message when he close the `System.out` @see end of  `public void messageSent(MessageEvent e)` ,`stream.close();` the System.out is closed and can not be used anymore, so good night to `System.out`

**The solution is:**

Removing the `stream.close();` command